# Array indexing issues

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to use a for loop to create 7 instances of a class. I can go through the loop 7 times, but once I press enter I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` error.

My code is as follows:

```
Data[] temperatures = new Data[7];


for(int i=1; i<=temperatures.length + 1; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for day " + i);
    temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-based in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Java array indexes]

Array indexes start at 0. The problem with your code is that you are trying to access the **8th array element which doesn't exist**. For more information, refer [The Java™ Tutorials - Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Your code should look something like this:

```
Data[] temperatures = new Data[7]; // Indexes 0-6 (makes a total of 7 indexes)

// Start the loop from index 0, end it to index 6 (= temperatures.lenght)
for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
    // Since it would sound strange to enter a temperature for day 0, notice (i+1)
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for day " + (i+1));
    temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array indexes start at 0. Therefore you must loop this way

```
 for(int i=0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because array index starts with 0, and it must not be greater than the array size.
In your case it *starts from 1 to 8* and you array size is 7.

```
for(int i=0; i<temperatures.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for day " + (i+1));
  temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
}
```

---

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

```
public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   extends IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Thrown to indicate that an **array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.**

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the error.

```
for(int i=1; i<=temperatures.length + 1; i++)
```

Your i in the loop should start from 0 as arrays in Java start from the 0th index.. Also your loop should go till i

This will navigate smoothly for 7 times.
Try this

```
for(int i=0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have index starting from 0 . IN your case indices would be 0 to 6 
Solution :
1. Change Loop to for(int i=0; i